# Incestual representation in genealogy tree

Tags: family-tree, complex-families

I am far from an expert when it comes to genealogy but I just had a random thought. How do you deal with complex incestual relationships in genealogy when trying to represent a family tree.

1. A father makes his own daughter pregnant, she gives birth to a boy. In this case, your son is also your grandson.
2. A son makes his own mother pregnant, she gives birth to a girl. In this case, your daughter is also your sister.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for visual representations, the following would be the simplest. Software programmes, using database information, would be able to add names, dates, additional generations, fancier formatting, etc. Genealogy software depends on linking people as spouses or as parents & children to determine relationships. There is also software that is oriented to health concerns, that can visually represent inherited medical and genetic issues, that occur in related people.

[image: Incest charts]